# Update/insert in new Android contacts API

Tags: android, api, contacts, contactscontract

When adding a contact in the new android contacts API, can I use **newAssertQuery()** also for insert, or will it only update an existing entry. If so, what is the difference between **newAssertQuery()** and **newUpdate()**?

More generally, do I need to check whether a raw contact or data exist first and then either insert or update, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this?